# SOAP to configure Wifi device

Tags: java, android, soap, httpclient

Using SoapUI, I send requests to a local Wifi device and get responses just fine. I would like to add a few of these to my Java/Android app just to do a simple check in the responses. For example, does the request below returns the string "apiVersion>1.1.4<" in the response? Everything I found so far is very old and I'm having a difficult time figuring it out. Any help is much appreciated!

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sdk="http://eero.lan/sdk/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sdk:getVersion/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```xml
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://eero.lan/sdk/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:getVersionResponse>
         <versionNumber>
            <apiVersion>1.1.4</apiVersion>
            <firmwareVersion>2.1.8</firmwareVersion>
         </versionNumber>
      </ns1:getVersionResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: SOAP is old and quite an exercise in Java, eg wsdl2java to create numerous client classes. If you are Spring competent then try https://www.baeldung.com/spring-soap-web-service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally found the perfect & simple solution at [https://technology.amis.nl/soa/how-to-call-a-call-a-webservice-directly-from-java-without-webservice-library/](https://technology.amis.nl/soa/how-to-call-a-call-a-webservice-directly-from-java-without-webservice-library)

Only had to solve the "Cleartext HTTP traffic to eero.lan not permitted" because the equipment doesn't support HTTPS. Added this line to AndroidManifest.xml in the application tag: Android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).